# MySQL Server won't start on non-standard port

Tags: mysql, firewall, port, mysql5.5

I am trying to allow external clients to access my database server through a extremely strict college firewall i.e. only ports 80 & 443 open. To allow clients to communicate with the server, I planned to change the port that the server listens on from (MySQL default) port 3306 to port 80. On changing the settings in the /var/mysql/my.cnf file to reflect the changes I wish to make, the mysql server refuses to start.

```
Server: Debian 8.0 x64
MySQL Server: 5.5.57-0+deb8u1
```

**Config for MySQL: (/etc/mysql/my.cnf)**

```
[client]
port        = 80
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 80
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Note: The only changes made are to [client] port, [mysqld] port, and commented 'bind-address'.

**On attempting to start the server, the log (/var/log/mysql/error.log) states:**

```
171013  1:25:50 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
171013  1:25:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
171013  1:25:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
171013  1:25:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
171013  1:25:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
171013  1:25:50 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
171013  1:25:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
171013  1:25:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
171013  1:25:50 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
171013  1:25:51  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
171013  1:25:52 InnoDB: 5.5.57 started; log sequence number 1595685
171013  1:25:52 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 80
171013  1:25:52 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
171013  1:25:52 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
171013  1:25:52 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Permission denied
171013  1:25:52 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 80 ?
171013  1:25:52 [ERROR] Aborting

171013  1:25:52  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
171013  1:25:52  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595685
171013  1:25:52 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This suggests that port 80 is being used by another process, but this is not true do to the server being a fresh install. With only MySQL-server and Fail2Ban installed extra, another process cannot be using it.

**'netstat -pln' confirms this:**

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3070/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3070/sshd
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     969834547 1/systemd           /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     969834550 1/systemd           /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     970364573 1/systemd           /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     972931518 5692/python         /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
```

Can anyone suggest a fix for this and/or give reasoning why the server won't start with port 80?

Comment: "root" permission is generally required to use ports < 1024.  Running mysql as root is usually not considered wise.

Comment: But if you really want to use port 80, you could run mysql on any port above 1024 (the default is a good choice) and then use iptables to forward port 80 traffic to the mysql port.

Comment: @BrandonXavier I am new to defining iptable rules, looking at other articles I get a basic understanding. Would the following work, assuming i wish for traffic to come in on port 80 and be sent to the mysql server at port 2404:

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2404

Comment: Here's a similar iptables solution: https://superuser.com/questions/661772/iptables-redirect-to-localhost#807612   Having mysql listen on the localhost interface is often considered a best practice for security as well (you can then get very granular with your iptables to only allow certain sources, etc. to reach your database)

Comment: Glad to help.  Might I suggest you summarize your solution in an answer and then mark it "answered"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Esa Jokinen suggested, I took down the HTTPS port of the server - and dedicated this to SSH. I then am allowed through the college firewall with a tunnel, as content isn't filtered. Using PuTTY I was able to create this tunnel and assign a port to it to allow the MySQL traffic through - works a treat!

For anyone wishing to do the same on Windows, I followed this guide;

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-with-putty/

Answer (score 0):

Given these limitations

- only ports `80` and `443` available

and keeping security in mind

- MySQL should not run as root (privileged ports `< 1024` needs root access)
- better avoid having MySQL listening on public IP

**I'd suggests having SSH or OpenVPN listening on port `443`.** This way, you can keep your MySQL on the default port `3306` and allow access only from `localhost` (in case of SSH tunneling) or the internal IP pool used by OpenVPN. Other reasons making this approach better include:

- Firewalls may have content filtering on port `80`. A transparent proxy would drop MySQL traffic as it's assuming only HTTP traffic.
- It's hard and not so common to try detect encrypted non-HTTPS traffic on port `443`. Therefore, both SSH and OpenVPN would work on most of the remote locations.
- You don't end up reserving port `80` or `443` for MySQL alone. That would mean that you can allow maximum of 2 different protocols, while using SSH tunneling or VPN you don't have any limitations, if the amount of services increases in the future.